# In how many ways can $18$ students be seated in two rows of $11$ seats if the first row is full and students sit together in the second row?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $18$ students and $2$ rows of $11$ seats. How many ways can you arrange the students if the first row must be always full and the $7$ students left must sit together?

My solution = 
$18C11 \cdot 11! \cdot 7! \cdot 5$

$18C11$ to choose $11$ people to sit at the first row, $11!$ to arrange them, 
$7!$ to arrange the $2$nd row, $5$ because there are $5$ ways to arrange them while sitting together, but I was told it was wrong.

What is the correct answer?

Comment: It may help if you show how you arrived at the _incorrect_ answer. We all learn by making mistakes, anyway.

Comment: I cannot find a mistake. You might as well state $18!\times 5$. There are $5$ possibilites to give $18$ persons a seat.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: ill check it with my teacher, thanks